# How to filter the string starting from a particular character and upto a character in javaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a javascript in which ha a need that I need the word which is inside two brackets.

for example

```
[Green]- Amazon
```

I need to extract the word Green from it , I can not use indexOf() as it can have other colors in the brackets as `[red]`, `[blue]` etc. I am not able to figure out how to get the characters exactly between the  two brackets.

can someone help me ?

Comment: use capturing groups `\[([^\]]*)\]` , please do a search.

Comment: What is the regular expression you already have? If you have none try http://regex101.com .

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple.use this to regex to match

```
\[(.*)\]
```